# How to iterate through a dict in pandas when some outputs will repeat

Tags: python, pandas

I have a series that starts with a state name and then list certain cities in that state, like so...

```
locations = ['Alabama', 'Auburn', 'Tuscaloosa', 'Alaska', 'Fairbanks', 'Arizona', 'Flagstaff', 'Tempe', 'Tuscon']
```

and a dict which takes state names and turns them into postal codes, like so...

```
state_codes = {'Alabama': 'AL', 'Alaska': 'AK', 'Arizona': 'AZ'}
```

what I want is a dataframe `x` with each postal code applied properly to each location, whether the location is a city or a state...

```
State              RegionName
'Alabama'          AL
'Auburn'           AL
'Tuscaloosa'       AL
'Alaska'           AK
'Fairbanks'        AK
'Arizona'          AZ
'Flagstaff'        AZ
'Tempe'            AZ
'Tuscon'           AZ
```

...but I can't quite seem to find the right code to get me there. I had been trying to use a temporary value that changes whenever a new state name is detected:

```
temp = 'fail'
newAreas = []
for k in range(0, len(locations)):
    if (locations[k] in state_codes.items()):
        temp = state_codes[locations[k]]
    newAreas.append(temp)
```

...but that returns a column of entirely the word 'fail.'  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: is you city is always come with the state, and is well ordered

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `map` and `ffill`

```
In [483]: locations = ['Alabama', 'Auburn', 'Tuscaloosa', 'Alaska', 'Fairbanks', 
                       'Arizona', 'Flagstaff', 'Tempe', 'Tuscon']

In [484]: state_codes = {'Alabama': 'AL', 'Alaska': 'AK', 'Arizona': 'AZ'}

In [485]: df = pd.DataFrame({'State': locations})

In [496]: df['RegionName'] = df['State'].map(state_codes).ffill()

In [497]: df
Out[497]:
        State RegionName
0     Alabama         AL
1      Auburn         AL
2  Tuscaloosa         AL
3      Alaska         AK
4   Fairbanks         AK
5     Arizona         AZ
6   Flagstaff         AZ
7       Tempe         AZ
8      Tuscon         AZ
```

Answer (score 2):

This is one way:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import chain

locations = ['Alabama', 'Auburn', 'Tuscaloosa', 'Alaska', 'Fairbanks', 'Arizona', 'Flagstaff', 'Tempe', 'Tuscon']
state_codes = {'Alabama': 'AL', 'Alaska': 'AK', 'Arizona': 'AZ'}

d = defaultdict(list)
for loc in locations:
    if loc in state_codes:
        current_loc = loc
    d[state_codes[current_loc]].append(loc)

# defaultdict(list,
#             {'AK': ['Alaska', 'Fairbanks'],
#              'AL': ['Alabama', 'Auburn', 'Tuscaloosa'],
#              'AZ': ['Arizona', 'Flagstaff', 'Tempe', 'Tuscon']})

df = pd.DataFrame(list(chain(*(((j, k) for j in v) for k, v in d.items()))),
                  columns=['State', 'RegionName'])

#         State RegionName
# 0     Alabama         AL
# 1      Auburn         AL
# 2  Tuscaloosa         AL
# 3      Alaska         AK
# 4   Fairbanks         AK
# 5     Arizona         AZ
# 6   Flagstaff         AZ
# 7       Tempe         AZ
# 8      Tuscon         AZ
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way. Create a mapping of location to state code. Then use this with `apply()`.

```
locations = ['Alabama', 'Auburn', 'Tuscaloosa', 'Alaska', 'Fairbanks', 'Arizona',
             'Flagstaff', 'Tempe', 'Tuscon']
state_codes = {'Alabama': 'AL', 'Alaska': 'AK', 'Arizona': 'AZ'}

# this assumes that the series that starts with a state name 
# and then list certain cities in that state as described in the OP
loc_to_state = {}
for l in locations:
    if l in state_codes:
        current_state = l
    else:
        loc_to_state[l] = state_codes[current_state]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['State', 'RegionName'])
df1['State'] = locations
df1['RegionName'] = df1['State'].apply(
    lambda x: x if x in state_codes else loc_to_state.get(x, 'fail')
)

print(df1)
#        State RegionName
#0     Alabama    Alabama
#1      Auburn         AL
#2  Tuscaloosa         AL
#3      Alaska     Alaska
#4   Fairbanks         AK
#5     Arizona    Arizona
#6   Flagstaff         AZ
#7       Tempe         AZ
#8      Tuscon         AZ
```

The dictionary `loc_to_state` looks like:

```
{
    'Auburn': 'AL',
    'Fairbanks': 'AK',
    'Flagstaff': 'AZ',
    'Tempe': 'AZ',
    'Tuscaloosa': 'AL',
    'Tuscon': 'AZ'
}
```

The dictionary `get()` function return the value if the key exists in the dictionary. Otherwise, it will return `'fail'`.

Comment: Is this assuming city always follow with right state ?

Comment: Yes, I added a comment about that. OP said: _"series that starts with a state name and then list certain cities in that state"_.

Comment: Yep, Since we all assuming that , I adding my solution :-)

Answer (score 1):

Data from Zero

```
pd.Series(state_codes).get(df.State).ffill()
Out[1250]: 
State
Alabama       AL
Auburn        AL
Tuscaloosa    AL
Alaska        AK
Fairbanks     AK
Arizona       AZ
Flagstaff     AZ
Tempe         AZ
Tuscon        AZ
dtype: object
```